# How to drop all Snort alarts that Intergration with Ryu controller?

Tags: sdn, mininet, snort, ryu

I have standard simple_switch_snort.py script app from Ryu controller
how can I drop all alerts events from snort that will applied as flow in switch ?
Actually, I don't know the right way. Can you guide me?
or shulde be deop from snort and how?
I need someone more experienced on Ryu and developing itself to point me to the right direction. Thank you.
see the simple_switch_snort.py script below :

```
@set_ev_cls(snortlib.EventAlert, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
def _dump_alert(self, ev):
    msg = ev.msg

    print('alertmsg: %s' % ''.join(msg.alertmsg))

    self.packet_print(msg.pkt)

@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures, CONFIG_DISPATCHER)
def switch_features_handler(self, ev):
    datapath = ev.msg.datapath
    ofproto = datapath.ofproto
    parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

    match = parser.OFPMatch()
    actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
                                      ofproto.OFPCML_NO_BUFFER)]
    self.add_flow(datapath, 0, match, actions)

def add_flow(self, datapath, priority, match, actions):
    ofproto = datapath.ofproto
    parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

    inst = [parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS,
                                         actions)]

    mod = parser.OFPFlowMod(datapath=datapath, priority=priority,
                            match=match, instructions=inst)
    datapath.send_msg(mod)

@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
def _packet_in_handler(self, ev):
    msg = ev.msg
    datapath = msg.datapath
    ofproto = datapath.ofproto
    parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
    in_port = msg.match['in_port']

    pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)
    eth = pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]

    dst = eth.dst
    src = eth.src

    dpid = datapath.id
    self.mac_to_port.setdefault(dpid, {})


    self.mac_to_port[dpid][src] = in_port

    if dst in self.mac_to_port[dpid]:
        out_port = self.mac_to_port[dpid][dst]
    else:
        out_port = ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD

    actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port),
               parser.OFPActionOutput(self.snort_port)]

    if out_port != ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD:
        match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst)
        self.add_flow(datapath, 1, match, actions)

    data = None
    if msg.buffer_id == ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:
        data = msg.data

    out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id,
                              in_port=in_port, actions=actions, data=data)
    datapath.send_msg(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

inside packet_print() function :

```
print("drop rules")
for datapath in self.datapaths.values():
   ofproto = datapath.ofproto
   parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
   match = parser.OFPMatch(eth_src=src_eth)
   action = []
   self.add_flow(datapath, 3, match, action, block-time)
```

action=[]>> block